# Where is Save Session button in the Graph API explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to submit bugs about the graph API to facebook and they have a field for "Graph API Explorer Repro URL"  The instructions are as follows:

Please provide a repro instance URL that describes the bug:

1. Get an access token by clicking on the "Get Access Token" button. Select permissions and select "Get Access Token".
2. Create your Graph API or FQL query that reproduces the issue. Test your query by clicking on the "Submit" button.
3. Click "Save Session" button to save your repro instance.
4. Copy paste the URL into the "Graph API Explorer Repro URL" field on the bug creation dialog. For example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?session_id=411486588960534

However, I don't see a Save Session button.  Here's my screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/fWqPitPU

Am I missing it or do I need to do something in my permissions to allow for the save session button to show?

Comment: Just ignore it. I think you can copy paste the URL without session_id, such as https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed

Comment: Nope, it does not accept that. #expletives deleted#

Answer (score 4):

Save session button is available towards Down-Right corner of the Facebook Graph API Explorer page. Once, you have saved the session, you can copy the URL and submit it with the bug report.